# Is it possible to get some string String in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

**Help me Señor**, :(

Is it possible to get some string String in EditText and show it to list view? 
I am using SQLite for my db. 
(sorry for my english)..

input word : `text_1  +text_2 +text_3`

List view : `text_1 text_2 text_3`

**screenshot**

[image]